# Microsoft Dynamics CRM or SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

In my organisation we write many custom mobile solutions for many different clients. We have started utilizing Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 in some of our test products however almost all of the work we are using it for is done with custom entities and the solutions are utilizing it as a back-end database. From my impressions so far, using CRM in this way is counter-intuitive and slow.

From your experience, would there be any benefit I am not seeing by using CRM instead of a normal SQL Server? I have only seen very basic stuff on the CRM front-end but am not sure how the custom entities become useful in CRM?

Comment: I think you are approaching this from the wrong angle. The question isn't so much "Which is better?", but rather "Which platform will help me best solve my (specific) business problems?". It would make more sense to me to present a specific problem where you think Dynamics CRM behaves clumsily for your organization and see if a concrete solution is at all possible.

Answer (score 5):

I write a lot of code for CRM and you are right, it isn't quick. It's benefits aren't for the developer though, they are for the end user. Through workflow and customisation they can create their own system to their own needs and can use the in-built entities to help manage their businesses.

That said, if you are not putting CRM in front of the customer (or using it internally for its true purpose) and are just using it as a database for your application, then this is not a good approach. You'd be better off talking directly to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft (and many partners) leverage Dynamics CRM as a platform for rapid and extensible development.  There is a term we use: [xRM](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2011/02/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-the-evolution-of-crm-to-xrm/) that implies you can build many different applications types faster than traditional custom development.

I have used Dynamics CRM in situations simply because of it amazingly granular security capabilities (and built a custom UI for most of the users).  Building a row-level security mechanism with the capabilities found in OOB Dynamics CRM 2011 would be a daunting task in itself...I often tell my new CRM developers, "when you are building *your* CRM, make sure you include: user data imports, row-level security, solution file deployments, simple form customization, custom views, etc."

With CRM 2011, you *start* with all of that and have a product with well designed extension points (plugins, workflows, web resources, JScript API, OData, SOAP).  All without writing, testing, debugging a single line of code.  The other thing I tell developers: coding is expensive, so don't write code :)